# How do I apply the Unity theme to LibreOffice on Kubuntu?

Tags: unity, kubuntu, libreoffice

I installed Kubuntu 11.10 and installed Unity on it. But still LibreOffice follows the KDE icon theme . How do I get Ubuntu's default icon theme in LibreOffice?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by removing `libreoffice-style-oxygen` package:

```
sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-style-oxygen
```